# How do I create Groups for custom users in Django?

Tags: django, django-custom-user

I created a Custom User Model by basically copying and pasting the full example given in the Django Docs. But in the docs, they unregistered groups. But in my project I will need groups because I'll have different uper types. So how can I still have groups and add my custom users to them?

Comment: Clarify your question more please

Comment: I'm actually following along a tutorial that uses Groups to differentiate different types of users like admin, customer etc. But I needed to build custom user model for my project. I kinda copied the example given in Django docs but realized that in the admin.py file, they unregistered the Groups. So in my admin page I don't see groups. Now I need to find a way to have Groups and add users created through my custom models there. But I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Try using a customGroup class extending the Group class, or a custom group class from scratch according to requirements